# Why is my Spring Integration split and aggregate gradually slowing down when handling a big list?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to transform all entries in a big (more than 1 million entries) list using Spring. I have reduced my use case to the following Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class IntegrationTestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntegrationTestApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationTestGateway integrationTestGateway;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IntegrationTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow splitAndAggregate() {
        return f -> f
                .split()
                .<Integer, String>transform(this::integerToString)
                .aggregate();
    }

    public String integerToString(Integer i) {
        logger.info("Converting {}.", i);
        return i.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        List<Integer> integers = new Random().ints(1000000, 0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> strings = integrationTestGateway.integersToStrings(integers);
    }

    @MessagingGateway
    private interface IntegrationTestGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "splitAndAggregate.input")
        List<String> integersToStrings(List<Integer> integers);
    }
}
```

In the begining, everything looks fine in the log:

```
2016-10-09 20:52:36.679  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 40.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.679  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 8.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.680  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 55.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.680  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 31.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.681  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 41.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.681  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 1.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.682  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 62.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.682  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 56.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.683  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 80.
2016-10-09 20:52:36.683  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 26.
```

However, after some 130000 entries have been handled, there is a delay of more than 100 ms between each message:

```
2016-10-10 08:11:19.710  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 64.
2016-10-10 08:11:19.868  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 3.
2016-10-10 08:11:20.015  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 18.
2016-10-10 08:11:20.174  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 42.
2016-10-10 08:11:20.302  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 0.
2016-10-10 08:11:20.468  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 16.
2016-10-10 08:11:20.607  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 6.
2016-10-10 08:11:20.749  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 46.
2016-10-10 08:11:20.902  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 82.
2016-10-10 08:11:21.043  INFO 48589 --- [main] s.s.IntegrationTestApplication           : Converting 23.
```

In my actual code, this delay has increased to more than five seconds after handling 500 k entries.

Is there a way I can speed this up? If possible, I still want to use Spring Integration, since my real world use case is more complex and needs threading and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, unfortunately, the default code has a check that prevents a message with an existing sequence number from being added - this causes a linear search across the current message contents which will cause the behavior you are seeing.

This is only done if the release strategy is a `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`.

If you use a custom release strategy then you can avoid that check, which is not necessary in this case.

Try the following:

```
.aggregate(a -> a.releaseStrategy(new MyReleaseStrategy()))
```

and

```
public static class MyReleaseStrategy implements ReleaseStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean canRelease(MessageGroup group) {
        return group.getSequenceSize() == group.size();
    }

}
```

I added a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4137).

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the correct direction although `group.getOne().getHeaders().get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER, Integer.class)` always returned `1` for me. I have updated the answer with a return statement that worked for me and will accept this after the change has been approved.

Comment: Cool; thanks; doh - my only excuse is it was 4am :) - my suggestion should have been `SEQUENCE_SIZE` (not ...NUMBER) but yours is more elegant although it does the same thing).